# How to fix ' FlatButton hidden behind the keyboard'?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I Have a widget showModalBottomSheet .. inside it has a class (AddTaskScreen),
But FlatButton hidden behind the keyboard .. What should I do to make it visible?

this is code :

```
 class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Add Task',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (newText) {
              newTaskTitle = newText;
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<TaskData>(context).addTask(newTaskTitle);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried this solution but doesn't work :

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
  child: FlatButton()
)
```

this is image [ScreenShot of my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl6f9.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with the code and some screenshoot. Would be nice.

Comment: I did it, brother .. you can check my screenshot. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger bottom sheet using this code

```
void openBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              AddTaskScreen(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

make sure we wrap **AddTaskScreen** with **Wrap** so it will efficiently rendered.

and we also wrap it with **Padding** and its value of **viewInsets.bottom**

this is the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Add Task',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          TextField(
            autofocus: false,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (newText) {
              newTaskTitle = newText;
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtomSheetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  void openBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              AddTaskScreen(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Bottom Sheet",
        ),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
              onPressed: () {
                openBottomSheet(context);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_bottom_sheet_padding) of example working-app.

[image: Demo]

Comment: I updated my answer, please check working-app repository as additional resources you may need

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you container in SingleChildScrollView() widget. By this, user can scroll to view the button.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
```

Comment: Try mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly in column.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Container in a ListViewBuilder so that the button can be scrolled up/down.  I think I got the parenthesis correct below:

```
return ( ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

    return ( Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Add Task',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (newText) {
              newTaskTitle = newText;
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<TaskData>(context).addTask(newTaskTitle);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ) );

}));
```